# JavaScript Promise wrapped in function or bare?

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise

If I'm calling a function that is a promise, do I need to do this "wrap it in another function" layer?

```js
Promise
.resolve()
.then(()=>{ // this part seems excessive
  return new Promise(resolve={
  // my function's guts
```

Can I return the new promise directly, like

```
Promise
.resolve()
.then(new Promise(resolve={
  // my function's guts
```

Comment: no. .then needs a function. Otherwise, you mightaswell have used .all because they're running in parallel.

Comment: The function is necessary, because it's not called right away. It's asynchronous. If the function wrapper wasn't there, it would be executed immediately. You can't eat a pizza that hasn't been delivered yet.

Comment: any non function value for .then's onFullfilled or onRejected arguments are ignored

Comment: relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I'm calling a function that is a promise, do I need to do this
>   "wrap it in another function" layer?

Yes otherwise it'll be executed immediately I recommend you create your promises within a named function that way it allows you to keep your chain neat and readable and code more reusable.

```js
myTask1()
  .then(myTask2)
  .then(myTask3);

function myTask1() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    console.log("Task 1");
    resolve("Task 1");
  })
}

function myTask2() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log("Task 2");
      resolve("Task 2");
    }, 1000)

  })
}

function myTask3() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    console.log("Task 3");
    resolve("Task 3");
  })
}
```

> Can I return the new promise directly, like.... `.then(new Promise(resolve={`?

No there's one critical difference with instantiating the promise like that. When you wrap the promise in a function it isn't evaluated until the previous promise completes whereas if you instantiate it inline then it's evaluated immediately which may cause unexpected results:

```js
new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve()
  })
  .then(new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    console.log("Task 1");
  }))
  .then(new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log("Task 2");
      resolve("Task 2");
    }, 1000);
  }))
  .then(new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    console.log("Task 3");
    resolve("Task 3");
  }))
```

To make the above work you could change it so that the closure returns a promise, but it starts to look pretty messy:

```js
new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve()
  })
  .then(() => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      console.log("Task 1");
      resolve("Task 1");
    })
  })
  .then(() => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        console.log("Task 2");
        resolve("Task 2");
      }, 1000);
    });

  })
  .then(() => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      console.log("Task 3");
      resolve("Task 3");
    });
  })
```

Answer (score 1):

You do have to wrap the promise in another function.

However, you can shorten it a bit because:

```
() => {
    return new Promise()
}
```

is the same as

```
() => new Promise()
```

So you could do something like this:

```
Promise
.resolve()
.then(() => new Promise(resolve => {
  // your function's guts
```

Comment: Why the `Promise.resolve()` part at all?  There does not seem to be any point to that.

Comment: Well, it's pointless so I'm not sure why you have it in your answer.  You don't need `Promise.resolve()` in order to use `new Promise()`

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to use `Promise.resolve()` when creating a new promise.

The usual way to create a promise is to make a function that returns the promise:

```
function myFunc() {
   return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
       // your async logic here
   });
}
```

Then, you call it like this:

```
myFunc().then(result => {
    // code that uses async result here
});
```

And, you have put your promise creation logic into a reusable function.

---

It is possible (though usually less practical) to create a new promise without putting it in a containing function.  For example, you can do this:

```
new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // async logic here that eventually calls resolve or reject
}).then(result => {
    // process async result here
}).catch(err => {
    // process error here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The handler for `then` could simply return a value.

```
Promise.resolve('value').then(() => 'otherValue');
```